# How to initialize a Lazy list?

Tags: .net, vb.net, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization, dnlib

I've read about [Lazy Initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but practically I don't understand how to initialize the objects inside.

This function returns a `LazyList` which is a kind of custom implementation of a [Lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type

```
Public Function GetMethods(ByVal Assembly As String,
                           ByVal TypeName As String) 'As List(Of MethodDef) ' As MethodDef()

    Dim methods As LazyList(Of MethodDef) = Nothing

    Using ass As ModuleDefMD = ModuleDefMD.Load(Assembly)

        For Each t As TypeDef In ass.GetTypes

            If t.HasMethods AndAlso t.Name.String.Equals(TypeName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then

                methods = t.Methods

                '  MsgBox(t.Methods.GetType.Name) ' Result: LazyList'1
                Exit For

            End If

        Next t

        Return methods

    End Using

End Function
```

When I try to read a property of any item of the LazyList I get a `NullReferenceException` exception, I suppose that this is because the object is not initialized? 'cause note that the lazylist item count is "2", and I'm totally sure that the property which I try to read can't be null.

```
Imports dnlib.DotNet
Imports dnlib.DotNet.Emit
Imports dnlib.Utils

    Dim methods As LazyList(Of MethodDef) = GetMethods("C:\WindowsApplication.exe", "Main")

    MsgBox(methods.IsInitialized(0)) ' Result: False
    MsgBox(methods.Count) ' Result: 2

    For Each method As MethodDef In methods

        ' NullReferenceException exception here:
        MsgBox(method.Name)

        ' NullReferenceException exception here too (reading m.hasbody):
        If method.HasBody Then
            Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            With sb
                .AppendLine(String.Format("Method Instructions: {0}", Environment.NewLine &
                                          String.Join(Environment.NewLine, method.Body.Instructions)))
            End With
            Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString)
        End If

    Next method
```

If I try to reproduce what I do in the code above (try to read the properties) but inside the function then all goes as expected without any nullreference exception... like in this example:

```
public function GetMethods (...)

' deleted code...

        If t.HasMethods AndAlso t.Name.String.Equals(TypeName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then

           methods = t.Methods
            For Each m In methods
                MsgBox(m.Name) ' no exceptions
                MsgBox(m.HasBody) ' no exceptions
            Next

       End If

' deleted code...

end function
```

PS: The imports are from [dnlib](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib) library.

> UPDATE:

I would like to explain the problem with more and better examples.

Two thinngs before continue explaining:

I ensured that in all examples the `TypeName` parameter exists and iis found, I've ensured that the returned collection of objects by the function never is empty, it has an Collection.Count of **2** as I've explained at the start of the question, so any of that is the problem.

---

Well, the next function returns a List of objects, those objects come with a property named `HasBody` but this property **ALWAYS** is empty (throwing a **NullReference** exception) when it should not be empty, the value should be **True** for the both items contained in the collection.

```
Public Function GetMethods(ByVal Assembly As String,
                           ByVal TypeName As String) As List(Of MethodDef)

    Dim methods As List(Of MethodDef) = Nothing

    Using ass As ModuleDefMD = ModuleDefMD.Load(Assembly)

        For Each t As TypeDef In ass.GetTypes

            If t.HasMethods AndAlso t.Name.String.Equals(TypeName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then

                methods = t.Methods.ToList
                Exit For

            End If

        Next t

        Return methods

    End Using

End Function
```

By the other hand, If I perform a ridiculous modification in the function (see the changes related to the `tmp` object) the function returns a list of objects where the `HasBody` property is initialized, is not empty, and the 2 items contained in the returned list a `HasBody` property with a value of **True**.

```
Public Function GetMethods(ByVal Assembly As String,
                           ByVal TypeName As String) As List(Of MethodDef)

    Dim methods As List(Of MethodDef) = Nothing

    Dim tmp As Object

    Using ass As ModuleDefMD = ModuleDefMD.Load(Assembly)

        For Each t As TypeDef In ass.GetTypes

            If t.HasMethods AndAlso t.Name.String.Equals(TypeName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then

                methods = t.Methods.ToList
                For Each m In methods
                    tmp = m.HasBody
                Next

                Exit For

            End If

        Next t

        Return methods

    End Using

End Function
```

So where is the problem here and how to fix it?, maybe that is a temporal solution for this situation but the `methoddef` object that returns the function contains a lot of properties and I need to access to more properties than `HasBody` in the future so I really can't be "assigning" each property to the `tmp` object in the function to solve that in a ugly way...

and the code used for loop through the returned List in both cases whas this:

Note: remember that, with the first function I can't parse the `method.hasbody` property and neither the `method.body.instructions` property, both throw a NullReference exception.

But with the modified function I can parse the `method.hasbody` property only if I've assigned it to the `tmp` variable inside the function before returning the List, and the same for the `method.body.instructions` property if did the same.

```
    Dim methods As List(Of MethodDef) =
        GetMethods("C:\WindowsApplication.exe", "Main")

    For Each method As MethodDef In methods

        MsgBox(method.Name)

        If method.HasBody Then
            Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            With sb
                .AppendLine(String.Format("Method Instructions: {0}", Environment.NewLine &
                                          String.Join(Environment.NewLine, method.Body.Instructions)))
            End With
            MsgBox(sb.ToString)
        End If

    Next method
```

Comment: What object was null when you got the exception?

Comment: @usr "HasBody" and "Body.Instructions" properties, but I supose that really a lot more of properties that I did not verified if were null (when it should not be NULL). please see my question update if you could, thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the first problem:

```
Public Function GetMethods(ByVal Assembly As String,
                       ByVal TypeName As String) 'As List(Of MethodDef)
```

Specify the return type and it may work: `As LazyList(Of MethodDef)`

This will also happen when the `TypeName` is not found in the Assembly.  In that case, your LazyList will still be Nothing and result in the NRE.  You should check the return - I dont think it has to do with the LazyList (yet):

```
Dim methods As LazyList(Of MethodDef) = _
     GetMethods("C:\WindowsApplication.exe", "Main")

If methods IsNot Nothing Then
  ' iterate
```

TestBed:

```
Dim methods As LazyList(Of MethodDef) = Nothing
```

In a button click:

```
methods = Test_Handler("Test2")

For Each meth As MethodDef In methods
    If meth.HasBody Then
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has a body", meth.Name)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has NO body", meth.Name)
    End If
Next
```

Test handler is essentially what you have &= `As LazyList(Of MethodDef)`.  Output:

```
.ctor has a body
testfunction has a body
Foo has a body
Bar has a body
ziggy has a body
```

The bigger problem may come next: *... I don't understand how to initialize the objects inside*

What you stored in the LazyList are these `MethodDef` objects -- they are already instantiated. `TypeDef.Methods` actually returns an IList of `MethodDef`, the only reason a LazyList is involved is because your code stores them that way.

If you mean to invoke the method(s) they describe, I am pretty sure you cant do it using a `MethodDef` as a starting point.  They are just metadata describing the characteristics of the method.  You already know the `TypeName` they came from so to invoke one of the methods, you'd have to have an instance of that Type.

Its unknown *what* you are trying to do, but a LazyList seems unneeded for a collection of metadata.

---

The definition in Object Browser for `Methods` is `IList`, as the source also shows:

```
public ThreadSafe.IList<MethodDef> Methods
```

Internally, *it* uses a LazyList.  This is probably so it can create and save a list of Methods for a Type but not bother loading the metadata for them unless and until it is actually asked something about the Methods list.  *Then* they are initialized.

This works equally well:

```
Private Function Test_Handler(typeName As String) As List(Of MethodDef)

    Dim modDef As ModuleDefMD = ModuleDefMD.Load("C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication1.exe")
    Dim methods As New List(Of MethodDef)

    For Each t As TypeDef In modDef.GetTypes

        ' stupid way to drill, but will work for demo purposes
        If t.Name.Equals(typeName) Then

            'methods = t.Methods
            methods.AddRange(t.Methods.ToArray)

            Exit For
        End If

    Next

    Return methods

End Function
```

You can get too clever and try to just do: `Return t.Methods` and get a cast error about LastList cast to List.  The set of method objects you get back is already instanced though, so there might be something else messed up if you are getting NREs.

---

**This solves the problem:**

```
Using ass As ModuleDefMD = ModuleDefMD.Load(Assembly)
```

The List of Method defs are internally a LazyList and wont be instanced until a Property or Method on them is called.  To instance them, they (apparently) need access to the thing that created them.  So reference something innocuous so you can dispose of `ModuleDefMD`

```
Dim methods As New List(Of MethodDef)
Dim b As Boolean

Using modDef As ModuleDefMD = ModuleDefMD.Load("C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication1.exe")
    For Each t As TypeDef In modDef.GetTypes

        ' stupid way to drill, but will work for demo purposes
        If t.Name.Equals(typeName) Then

            For Each m As MethodDef In t.Methods
                b = m.HasBody

                methods.Add(m)

            Next
            Exit For
        End If

    Next
End Using
Return methods
```

This is more or less what you Tmp object does.  You call it ugly, but since the source is a LazyList, it is either that or work out something with the `modDef` reference.

Comment: setting the return type as 'LazyList(Of MethodDef)' did not solved the problem. also you say that the only thing why a Lazy is involved is because me, but not, I really don't want to use a Lazy, but if I get the type of the data tu return while I'm inside the function it is a LazyList as seen in the code above (t.Methods.GetType.Name). none of the commented solved the problem, please see my question update where I've published codes that will help to understand better the problem, thanks for answer

Comment: Two Edits...you cant assign the dnLib to your list variable, or you **will** need a LazyList and perhaps some calls to helper functions.

Comment: If I just try to use the `methods.AddRange(t.Methods.ToArray)` and return the list it don't works, by the other hand the function that you've provided works, yes its true, but no matter the `lazylist`, the only important difference from your function and mine is the usage of the IDisposable `ModuleDefMD` object, I dispose it in my function and seems that it's associated in some way with the returned list, i really don't know why! but is that, if I don't dispose the `ModuleDefMD` (like in your function) I can read all the properties after returning the List.

Comment: I just can say Thanks for be helping always to others, including in some kind of strange questions that includes 3rd party underground libraries like this time, thanks a lot.

Comment: But now the problem is how I could dispose that object without "loosing" the list item-properties, lol.

Comment: Ahhh!  I did not really notice the Using block.  Those module def objects must rely on it to be initialized (I had a cast problem at one point using ToList) .  Seems strange it works since it that ModuleDefMD out of scope.  Referencing them though using the TMP variable also instanced them, I assumed the same thing would happen with ToArray, but apparently thats only if/when your really use it.  BTW the only thing really wring with the LIB is the lack of docs and Intellisence help - all there is is those examples; but so far I cant see what it does that you cant do with Reflection.

Comment: `how I could dispose that object` it really isnt all that hard to reference something on each and then add to the list...see new edit.  Its a lot like your Tmp thing.  Since the internal source is a LazyList, some Prop or Meth needs to be invoked.